# Replace password key value pair in Json String

Tags: javascript, json

here the problem is, I want to replace password value as '**********' if i find password element in the string.

eg: string `"{"element" : "test1", "password": "dfsdn653##"}"`

should be replaced as

```
"{"element" : "test1", "password": "********"}"
//OR
"{"element" : "test1", "password": ""}"
```

i tried replacing the string using regex, but didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Can you share your attempts?

Comment: your "string" isn't valid though

Comment: show what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
var a = { "element": "test1", "password": "dfsdn653##" }
a.password = "".padStart(a.password.length, '*')
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))

//Some fixed length to not give away the actual length

a.password = "".padStart(7, '*')
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Comment: Or a fixed length to not give away the length of the password

Comment: @mplungjan nice idea. Edited

Comment: Possibly stringify the object back to string since console.log prettyprints the object

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to object using `JSON.parse()` and then change the `password`.Create an array of `password.length` and `fill()` it with `*` and `join()` it.

```js
let str = `{"element" : "test1", "password": "dfsdn653##"}`;
let obj = JSON.parse(str);
obj.password =Array(obj.password.length).fill('*').join('');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Since .fill has same support as padStart, I'd say padStart is the winner

Answer (score 0):

If you show the string `'············'` to the length of what you are typing like `'I Like Pizza'` using a custom function like this:

```
var toAsterisk = function(string) {
  var asterisks = "";
  for(var i = 0; i > string.length; i++) {
    asterisks = asterisks + "·"
  }
}
```

If you show your string as asterisks but you are adding to a different string that contains the password then you would be able to have a hidden password.

(Hope this helps!)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonStr = '{"element" : "test1", "password": "dfsdn653##"}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty('password')) {
  var res = jsonObj.password.split('').map(elem => elem = '*').join('');
  jsonObj.password = res;
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```